# c# windows application crashes after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i recently developed a c# windows application with visual studio 2010. My application was consisted by 2 projects, the main one and a setup project.

In my PC and Laptop everything works fine (i have vs2010 installed in both). I install the application and run it without problems.

The problem is that after installing it on other machines, i run the app and after a few second i get this message:

```
Signature problem:
 Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
 Signature problem 01: "myapplication_name".exe
 Signature problem 02: 1.0.0.0
 Signature problem 03: 4fc25af5
 Signature problem 04: System.Data.SqlServerCe
 Signature problem 05: 3.5.1.0
 Signature problem 06: 4b743b2d
 Problem Signature 07: 49e
 Signature problem 08: 25
 Signature problem 09: System.AggregateException
 OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
 Locale ID: 1033
 Additional Information 1: 4be7
 Additional Information 2: 4be78fdd727e4350d8f2189583321f8d
 Additional Information 3: ee32
 Additional Information 4: ee3246da456e2a0eb853eb97402fe5f6

 Reading the statement our privacy while you're online:
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0408

 If online privacy statement is not available, read the privacy statement offline:
 C: \ Windows \ system32 \ el-GR \ erofflps.txt
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your program possibly need .Net framework installed?

Comment: Have you used a autogenerated certified? If so, maybe it is only valid in your machine.

Comment: while setup is starting is looking if net framework 4 is present and if not it downloads and installs it automaticly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it can't find SQL Server Compact Edition on the target PC.  You need to add a reference to it in your installer

Does this help?:

- [MSDN: How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The prerequisites components of the application are: 1.Net Framework Client profile x84 x64 2.SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 and Windows Installer 3.1

Comment: OK i figured it out. You were right about the SQL CE. I had it as a prerequisite in the first project but NOT in the setup project!! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @MarcusV You're welcome, glad it helped. If you click on the tick to the left of this answer, it marks your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured it out. You were right about the SQL CE. I had it as a prerequisite in the first project but NOT in the setup project!! Thank you very much for your help